# cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport height equal to page height (height 100%)

Tags: html, css, angular

Trying to get **cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport** height to be equal to **page height.**

```
<div class="plServiceItemsList-list">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport class="plServiceItemsList-listViewPort" itemSize="20">
```

When trying to use height **100%**, I see no list

```
.plServiceItemsList-listViewPort {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

The only way it will be displayed is specifying a height:

```
.plServiceItemsList-listViewPort {
  height: 100px;
}
```

But this is not **dynamic.**

Comment: Did you tired 100vh?

Comment: @Chellappan thanks! Works

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After @Chellappan suggested using vh, I thought my issue was solved, but actually, when the page size what bigger than the screen, it failed.

This is what I used:

```
.plServiceItemsList-listContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.plServiceItemsList-listViewPort {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MCMatan for sharing. I've been working to fill vertical space in a view between fixed header and footer using @angular/flex-layout, so I just used fxFlex="grow" on the scroller inside a flex container, just as you point out!

Comment: @MCMatan this solution doesn't do the trick for me, the listcontainer class is that just a div wrapped around the <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>?

Comment: not work for me. not change the height as expected